# How to update using upsert in MongoDB using JPA

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to add insert a record in MongoDB if the unique key combination doesn't exist else insert the record using JPA in springboot.

The code to insert is as follows. In the following id1 and id2 is a unique key.

```
@Autowired
MyEntityRepository  myEntityRepository;
.........
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
entity.setId1(id1);
entity.setId2(id2);
entity.setTime(time);
myEntityRepository.save(entity);
```

How to update the above using upsert?

Comment: Errm no, spring data mongodb does NOT use the jpa api

Answer (score 0):

myEntityRepository.save() already uses upsert. It will insert a new record if the key doesn't exists.

But I believe you want to save in MongoDB if it's new record and save in DB  only if it exists. In that case, you need to explicitly check if the records exists for the given key.